# Mapping from Dataframe using a unique pair of values

Tags: python, pandas

I have onde df1 with 30829 rows, where a player has a name and an id. names are repeated numerous times.

```
RangeIndex: 30830 entries, 0 to 30829
Data columns (total 18 columns):
...
player_id          30830 non-null int64
player_name        30830 non-null object
team               30830 non-null object
...
```

and another df2 where those players (not necessarily all of them) have only unique names and no ids.

```
RangeIndex: 762 entries, 0 to 761
Data columns (total 6 columns):
...
player        762 non-null object
team          762 non-null object
...
```

Now I need to get ids from df1, map them to df2 and add each id on a new column to its respective name.

I have tried:

```
df2['id'] = df2['player'].map(
                    lambda x: df1.loc[df1['player_name']==x, 'player_id'])
```

But It appears some players from two different teams have identical names, and ids are being doubled.

---

How do I fix this, mapping from a unique pair of values (player_id and team) instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `drop_duplicates` , then `map`

```
mapping=df1.drop_duplicates('player_name').set_index('player_name')['player_id']    
df2['id']=df2['player'].map(mapping)
```